# Unable to upload files to s3 via aws console. What can I check to find out the cause?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have gone through all the steps and got to the last page.

[image]

However the 'upload' button is disabled.

I have checked the browser console and there is no error message. So it is unlikely a front end issue.

Why the upload button is disabled? Is it due to the number of files and/or total size?

Comment: Can you try the GUI with one small file? Also try the cli - the command line is something like "aws s3 cp localfile.txt s3://bucket-name/remotefile.txt" to push a file up. I've done that with tens of GBs of files with one command, and it would probably take TB no problems. You have to set up your local AWS profile first with by running "aws configure" then entering appropriate keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could well be the number or total size, the web interface is more suited for a smaller jobs. I suggest you use a dedicated client tool to do that instead:

- If on Linux try **[aws-cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)** or **[s3cmd](https://s3tools.org/s3cmd)**
- On Windows try for example **[S3 Browser](http://s3browser.com/)**

There are plenty of tools around.